# Query data from sql database with "," separator

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new to SQL and looking at some code.  I can see the basic structure for getting items out of a Table where column="Apples" or something like that.

```
select * from fruitsTable where fruit="apple"
```

If the data can be

```
apple
orange
apple,orange
pear
apple,pear
```

Is there a way to make that query?  I know that apple,orange and apple,pear don't really make sense, but basically I'm trying to filter out the data from a database and sometimes it's just one, and other times it's two categories.  How would I filter/query the database for something like that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL you can use `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('apple', fruit)`.

For other databases you can use `WHERE (',' || fruit || ',') LIKE '%,apple,%'`.

In both cases the query can't use an index and it will be slow if your table is large.

Comment: +1 for the often overlooked simple answer. Would this have any implications on index performance?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from fruitsTable
where fruit like '%apple%'
```

What that query does is return all records that have the string 'apple' somewhere in the `fruit` field.

N.B. please don't design a database like this.  *Comma separated values* are a quick way to make a bad database.

Comment: That will also match on `Pineapple`, to use LIKE reliably you need something more like `',' & fruit & ',' LIKE '%,apple,%'`.  And yes, this is a Very bad design.  Better to have multiple rows, where associated rows share a key to relate them.